# Accessing spreadsheet A, from spreadsheet B

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Suppose we have the owner of spreadsheet B, which want to pull the data from spreadsheet A, through Apps Script.

Is it possible to pull the data from spreadsheet A, into B, if B owner doesn't have VIEW/EDIT access to the spreadsheet A.
So the target is that B can pull the data from A, through Apps Script, but cannot access the A directly with the link.

```
    function syncDown1(){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheetActive=ss.getActiveSheet();

      var masterSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
      var masterSheet = masterSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Referral Clients");

      var lastRowMaster = masterSheet.getLastRow();
      var lastRowPersonal = sheetActive.getLastRow();

      sheetActive.getRange(4,1,lastRowPersonal,14).clear();

      var agentName = sheetActive.getRange(1,2).getValue();

      if (agentName == "") {
          Browser.msgBox("You have to enter agent's name in cell B2");
          return;
      }

      var agentArray = masterSheet.getRange(1,2,lastRowMaster,1).getValues();

      Logger.log(agentArray);

      //personal sheet iterator
      var j = 4;

      for (var i=1; i<=agentArray.length; i++) {


          if (agentArray[i] == agentName) {

             //column A master
             sheetActive.getRange(j,1,1,1).setValues(masterSheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,1).getValues());

             //column G master
             sheetActive.getRange(j,2,1,1).setValues(masterSheet.getRange(i+1,7,1,1).getValues());

             //column C, D, E, F master
             sheetActive.getRange(j,3,1,4).setValues(masterSheet.getRange(i+1,3,1,4).getValues());

             //column I master
             sheetActive.getRange(j,7,1,1).setValues(masterSheet.getRange(i+1,9,1,1).getValues());

             //column K, L, M, N, O master
             sheetActive.getRange(j,8,1,5).setValues(masterSheet.getRange(i+1,11,1,5).getValues());

             j = j + 1;

          }

      }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see if if works. If it doesn't you'll have some code written that has generated an error and then you can ask why.

Comment: It works when B owner has an access to the A spreadsheet, but when B doesn't have an access (VIEW or EDIT) it shows an error "document is missing (perhaps it was deleted )...". 

Final target is that, the B cannot access the A directly, but can pull some data through the script.

Comment: If you can tell us more about what you’re trying to do maybe we can help you but right now it’s hard to figure out what you’re really trying to do it so it’s hard to help you. Try reading the documentation on how to ask good questions.

Comment: Here is the link to the spreadsheet and the script inside.
syncDown1() function is pullin the data from the master spreadsheet, and syncUp() function is pushing the data to the master spreadsheet.

https://script.google.com/macros/d/MPY4jsgJqZEHiJehI5LlbH1MUa9rkdzLv/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvHVALAniiZHUXMv1KU4d3saJP411XPaQiust077--KQySuXGZDyq107moRGkHxyl6kO4GIA5tGfOrSxHuA1u-m2vU58MFo2ly7pLp_k5lIM4qFkmss-V93eZM5dQp14pD_Qft7w9g